# Running date +%s command from a file

Tags: unix, date

When I run the command `date +%s` directly on unix terminal, it correctly executes and gives number of seconds since 1970.

However, when the same command is in a script file, say temp.sh as below:

```
business_dt=date +%s
echo $business_dt
```

On executing above script, it throws error as below:

```
-ksh: +%s: not found [No such file or directory]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **command substitution** to assign the output of a command to a variable. The syntax is `var=$(command)`. So, try changing your script to:

```
business_dt=$(date +%s)
```